# How to solve constraints with boolean and bitvector variables in c/c++ interface of stp

Tags: smt, bitvector, stp

Suppose I have the following constraints

```
(declare-fun x () Bool)
(declare-fun y () Bool)
(declare-fun t1 () (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-fun t2 () (_ BitVec 8))
(assert (or x y))
(assert (=> x (bvule t1 t2)))
(assert (=> y (bvule t2 t1)))
(check-sat)
```

How to write the corresponding code in c/c++ interface of stp?
My application requires to solve a constraint set similar to this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [C API testcases](http://people.csail.mit.edu/vganesh/STP_files/cinterface.tar.gz). There are a number of small, easy to read examples for how to use STP's C interface. Here is push-pop.c.

```
/* g++ -I$(HOME)/stp/c_interface push-pop.c -L$(HOME)/lib -lstp -o cc*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "c_interface.h"

int main() {
  VC vc = vc_createValidityChecker();
  vc_setFlags('n');
  vc_setFlags('d');
  vc_setFlags('p');
  //vc_setFlags('v');
  //vc_setFlags('s');

  Type bv8 = vc_bvType(vc, 8);

  Expr a = vc_varExpr(vc, "a", bv8);
  Expr ct_0 = vc_bvConstExprFromInt(vc, 8, 0);

  Expr a_eq_0 = vc_eqExpr(vc, a, ct_0);

  int query = vc_query(vc, a_eq_0);
  printf("query = %d\n", query);

  vc_push(vc);
  query = vc_query(vc, a_eq_0);
  vc_pop(vc);

  printf("query = %d\n", query);
}
```

This corresponds to the smt query:

```
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 8))
(push)
(assert (not (= a (_ bv0 8))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

Once you have gotten a couple of these working, you can take a look at the [c interface header](https://github.com/stp/stp/blob/master/src/interface/C/c_interface.h) for how to construct different operators.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tim. Could you tell me how to declare and manipulate boolean variables?

Comment: Try combining vc_boolType and vc_boolType to get a boolean variable. For manipulating boolean variables, you probably are going to have to read the c_interface.h header. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of stp built in order to test this.